# How to add javascript to an image from the content_wrapper in the css stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, background, stylesheet

I am creating a website (http://yic.am) using wordpress and the theme includes a background and a "subpage_content_bg". The subpage-background is a semi-transparent white background that wraps  around the content making it easier to read. I would like the subpage background to become `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute` when you scroll down, so that when it reaches the top of the page it scrolls with the page.

I have found several pages describing and demonstrating the function when the subject is a picture, comment box or text in the actual post or page. However, I cannot seem to find a description for when the picture is a part of the css stylesheet.

The subpage-extract from the stylesheet looks like this:

```
#sp .content_wrapper_sbl {
    width:940px;
    min-height:320px;
    margin:-107px auto 0;
    padding:45px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
    background:url(../../images/subpage_content_bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
            }
```

Where should I place the javascript for the function (I am trying to use the function from the above link)? I would like it to be for all pages and posts (except the cover-page)

How do I make the subpage image the target of the function? Is it possible to make the `#sp` or `content_wrapper_sbl` the target?

I have been trying a lot of different things for a lot of times - but I am very new to web-designing and coding. I hope all the necessary information is included - any help would be much appreciated.

The code I am working is this: http://jsfiddle.net/EahRx/870/

Comment: Firstly, it'd be really handy if you could post a fiddle of your actual code so we can try and figure out where you're going wrong - it's difficult to point you in the right direction if we are flying blind :)

Comment: Secondly, judging by your CSS, it looks like you could target `.content_wrapper_sbl` with your jQuery, like `$('content_wrapper_sbl').css({position:fixed})` or whatever. Your javascript (or jQuery), by the way, should still stay in your `.js` document.

Comment: @Doug thanks for your fast reply! I thought `content_wrapper_sbl` was maybe the one to target but I do not know how to do it. I have added a fiddle with the code I am trying to use but it is only html and javascript - no css. And which `.js` document should it be placed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've pretty much got it nailed in that fiddle, haven't you? It's personal preference how you want to arrange your javascript files, I guess. Personally, I like to use the Google library to load my jQuery...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then load any other plugins you might be using...

```
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin1.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin3.js"></script>
```

and finally I usually build a custom jQuery file and call it, surprise surprise, "jquery.custom.js"...

```
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.custom.js"></script>
```

So the final javascript include list looks like this...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin1.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.custom.js"></script>
```

This way the jQuery library is loaded first because the likelihood is that all other javascript files depend on it. Then the plugins are loaded, finally your custom file is loaded because that might depend on some of the earlier plugins being loaded first - for example, your custom file might want to tweak a slideshow file loaded in one of your plugins.

If, for any reason, you are not able to edit the head of your template file to add your javascript include you can add it to the bottom of your HTML like this...

```
<head>
[META INFO & TITLE]
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin1.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.plugin3.js"></script>
[CSS AND STUFF]
</head>

<body>
[YOUR WEB PAGE STUFF]
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.
Oh, and remember to add the old "document ready" gubbins to the jquery.custom.js file too...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    [YOUR JQUERY HERE]
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Doug! I have now tried to add the javascript include but I cannot find a right place: my header.php seems to be the one that includes the javascript references but I can not add a new script there. I found the bottom of my html in the footer.php file, but it will not add there either. There is a part about the content-wrapper in index.php but I don't think that is the right place either...

Comment: You should be able to modify the template files somehow... why are you not able to? If push comes to shove, you could modify an existing, unrelated javascript file to include your code but that's a messy workaround (for example http://yic.am/wp-content/themes/YIC/YIC-theme/js/common.js?ver=1.0.0).

Comment: In the header.php file the javascript files are listed as followed:

    `<?php //wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>

 <?php wp_enqueue_script('js_subpage'); ?>

 <?php wp_enqueue_script('js_watermarkinput'); ?>

        ...

        <?php wp_enqueue_script('js_custom');?`

I have added the `js_custom` but it is not listed with the others when I view the source of the page (some of the others are not listed either...)

Comment: Can you not see a `</body>` tag in there somewhere after those php includes? You could drop your javascript include in there.

Comment: okay, I have now added the script reference after the `</body>` tag. But there does not seem to be any effect. The `custom.js` file includes the same as in the fiddle above, except with `content_wrapper_sbl` instead of `#myDiv`. As far as I understand this should be enough to refer to the subpage-background in my stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry, put the include before the </body> tag not after.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!! I have now successfully added the `jquery.custom.js` before the `</body>` tag but it is not affecting the subpage-background at all. I have tried targeting different items (`content_wrapper_sbl`, `content_wrapper_sbr`, etc.). Any ideas?

Comment: I think at this stage you need to start using a development tool - Firebug, for example. If you do you will find that there is an error in your jquery.custom.js file `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`. I think your jQuery functions are in a different namespace (I think that's the correct terminology! I'm no jargon expert). Try replacing the occurrences of `$` with `jQuery` - e.g. `jQuery(document).ready(function(){[code here]});`

Comment: some progress! I changed all the `$` occurences to `jQuery` and the script is now definitely running on the site. I am using Chrome's own web development tool after your recommendation - very useful!! I still have a problem with targetting the subpage-background though... Targetting `.content_wrapper_sbr` does not have the desired effect - and targetting `.content` has the desired effect but on the content of the page (text, pics etc.). Is it possible to directly target the subpage-background mentioned in the css stylesheet? (`subpage_content_bg.png`)

Comment: I'm sure it must be possible... however at this stage I'm not sure how much more help I can be without sitting down for a few hours to unpick your code... I'm sorry but I haven't got time to do that :( It might be a CSS, HTML or jQuery issue. There are special tricks you can employ like adding the odd `console.log('My Message');` line in strategic places. This writes a message to the debugging console (in Chrome's web dev tool) that allows you to see whether particular segments of code are being executed or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for all your help! I hope I will manage in some way :)

Comment: I'm sure you will - you seem to be getting to grips with is rather well... the most important tool, perhaps, is the debugging console... absolutely essential! BTW, welcome to SO, and if you think any particular answer has been helpful, don't forget to accept it :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I am using chrome's own debugging console which is very useful! And I have accepted your answer now - it showed me how to add my javascript, which I am very grateful for :)